# C++11 alternative to boost::checked_delete

Tags: c++, c++11, std, language-lawyer

As a heavy user of forward declarations, I enjoy my classes being complete at destruction. To ensure this, I make the destructor private and befriend `boost::checked_delete`:

```
#include <boost/checked_delete.hpp>

struct MyClass
{
  //MyClass's interface
  private:
  ~MyClass() { /* something */ }
  friend void boost::checked_delete<>(MyClass* x);
};
```

In C++11, `std::default_delete` also checks for completeness at destruction. Nevertheless, I could not implement the same behaviour as above:

```
#include <memory>

struct MyClass
{
  //MyClass's interface
  private:
  ~MyClass() { /* something */ }
  friend struct std::default_delete<MyClass>;
};

int main()
{
  //const std::shared_ptr<MyClass> d { 
  //  std::make_shared<MyClass>() 
  //}; //(1) Should compile?

  const std::shared_ptr<MyClass> d(
    new MyClass,std::default_delete<MyClass>()
  ); //(2) Does compile
}
```

I wonder

1. How can I get the line marked (1) to compile? The use of `std::make_shared` is A Good Thing
2. Is the line marked (2) really valid? It feels bad to explicitly specify the deleter

I am using GCC 4.8.0 and I checked with both -std=c++11 and -std=c++1y flags.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete" in this context? Can you please give an example of what you mean by "class is complete" or "class is incomplete" on destruction? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a good first question, I've slightly edited it, including removing the closing `Thanks, Richel Bilderbeek`. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.

Comment: Doesn't GCC issue a warning/error when deleting incomplete type? Under VC 2013 I get a warning in case of raw/`shared_ptr` (can be promoted to an error with right options) and static assertion failure with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @utnapistim N3797 [basic.types]/5 "A class that has been declared but not defined, an enumeration type in certain contexts (7.2), or an array of unknown size or of incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object type. Incompletely defined object types and the void types are incomplete types (3.9.1). Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type." [expr.delete]/5: "If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: [At points in the program where the class type isn't complete, the compiler cannot have seen the class definition, and therefore doesn't know that the destructor is `private`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3435b8de7c8a33e7 "Demo at Coliru") I don't see how declaring the destructor private in any way protects against the class being deleted when incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
struct wrapper;

struct MyClass
{
private:
    ~MyClass() { /* something */ }
    friend wrapper;
};

struct wrapper
{
    MyClass obj;
};

// ...

auto const tmp = std::make_shared<wrapper>();
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p(tmp, &tmp->obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `make_shared` call in an initializer list, just do normal initialization:

```
const std::shared_ptr<MyClass> d = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
```

As for the second thing, if you don't specify a deleter then it will be the default deleter.

Comment: That is an initialization.

Comment: *"if you don't specify a deleter then it will be the default deleter."* For `unique_ptr`, but not for `shared_ptr`. The latter will just *call* `delete`, that is, the effetcs of the dtor are that `delete p` is called. It isn't specified *where* this call happens, and I doubt `default_deleter` is used (IIRC you can use inheritance at the bookkeeping-object level which can lower the amount of space overhead).